# Can't hide border of image in CSS

Tags: html, css, hide, border

There is a problem with hiding a border of image in **CSS**:

[image]

Logo is `<img>` - a tag, inside main `<div>`, I'm setting the border value so:

```
#map-logo {
    border: none;
...
}
```

to the `<img>` object, but border is visible, how to fix this in **CSS**?

Code and live sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    #map-control {
        width: 177px;
        height: 178px;
        background-image: url( 'http://s30.postimg.org/96b366cxp/image.png' );
    }

    #map-logo {
        border: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 85px;
        height: 85px;
        background-image: url( 'http://s30.postimg.org/is4nmh43h/image.png' );
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-control">
            <img id="map-logo" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you u define img tag background-image why ?

Comment: `<img>` tag required `src` attribute.

Comment: @RohitAzad Because google suggests it, I'm very weak in CSS and web-design, and don't know, hot to make it correctly, so if you can help me to solve this problem, please help, thank you very much!

Comment: @KheemaPandey always? and can't I to pass it? I've googled, the search gave me results, that I can set with some css properties, but I don't say, that my way is correct one, so if not to define src property to img, how to set background in CSS? Thanks!

Comment: @GeloVolro if you need to add a background you shouldn't use a `<img> element

Comment: @KheemaPandey thanks for your advice, when I've changed from `img` to `div` the border has dismissed. But I wonder why? Can you tell me more about reason why did such issue occur? It's interesting for me to understand better CSS and HTML handle by browser. Thanks!

Comment: when you use `img` tag with `<a>` then `border` appear; then you can remove border using `border:0` and when you use image as a `background` then by default you won't get a border. border appear only with <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `border: none` isn't valid.

It should be `border: 0`

**[NOTE]**
Strictly it should be `border-width: 0`, since `border` is shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`)

Comment: strange... I've set both: `border: 0` && `border-width: 0`, but no success! proves: http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/1/ -   (border: 0) && http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/2/ (border-width: 0)

Comment: Note Kheema Pandey's answer, you'll also need to set your `src`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: If to set `src=""` - empty, and not to remove `background-image` property, then border still exists, if to set the path in `src=""` and to remove `background-image` property, then all is working pretty fine. But I want to try not use `src=''` and to work with CSS purely, is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the src attribute on an image? Makes no sense to me. Either use `src` and remove the background ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/5/)), *or* use a `div` instead of an `img` ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/4/))

Comment: Yeah, Kheema Pandey has answer me, if to chamge `img` to `div`, then all will begin to work, and you've answered right now! Thanks! I just want to know about different variations, if you're telling me, that there is no sense, I shall keep this info in mind, thanks! I'm just a beginner in HTML/CSS :)

Comment: Can you also add some info about `div` variant, then I can set your answer as correct one, I've just want other visitors be able to know about different variants, thanks again! :)

Comment: `border: none` is valid, and changing it to `border: 0` does not change anything in rendering.

Answer (score 1):

`border:none` properties only apply when using `<img>`  tag with `src` attribute. in your case you are using `<img>` tag without `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
border: 0;
```

In the past I've come to know that `border: none;` does not work in some situations,

Comment: strange... I've set `border: 0 but no success! prove: http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/1/, and `border-width: 0` also doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/XCdbc/2/

Comment: @GeloVolro There doesn't seem to be a border? Are you talking about that empty space around the image? That's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include a doctype for consistency in rendering. The main modification below is to remove the img element replacing it with a div instead. If you insist on using the img tag make sure to provide a src attribute or you'll run into this since the renderer doesn't know what the default content should be (that's why the border shows as a place holder for where content should be).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    #map-control {
        width: 177px;
        height: 178px;
        background-image: url( 'http://s30.postimg.org/96b366cxp/image.png' );
    }

    #map-logo {
        border-width: 0;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 85px;
        height: 85px;
        background-image: url( 'http://s30.postimg.org/is4nmh43h/image.png' );
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-control">
            <div id="map-logo"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```